# I'm encountering an error with MaterialUI and could use some assistance. Any ideas?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui, visual-web-developer

I'm encountering this error when using TableCell component in my project:

> MUI: capitalize(string) expects a string argument

I've tried troubleshooting but can't seem to find the solution. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Code snippet:

```
<TableCell
  style={{
    color: "white",
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    fontWeight: "700",
  }}
  key={head}
  align={head === "Coin" ? null : "right"}
>
  {head}
</TableCell>
```

I've already attempted to troubleshoot by reviewing this code and ensuring that i am passing valid props to the TableCell component. Additionally, I've checked for any misconfigurations or conflicts with other dependencies.

However, despite my efforts, the error persists. i am expecting the TableCell component to render without any errors, allowing to display tabular data in the application.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

`align` expects one of the following values `'center'| 'inherit'| 'justify'| 'left'| 'right'`, `'inherit'` is the default. Replacing `null` with `'inherit'` should resolve your issue.